# Meaning of "noch" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the word "noch" mean in the following sentence?

> Ich ruf dich heute noch an.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69258/ich-werde-noch-heute-den-arzt-anrufen-or-noch-im-mai-hat-sie-ihre-dissertati

Comment: For a question tagged meaning-in-context the context given is surprisingly slim.

Comment: @guidot not only that, but the question is also lacking some research effort.

Answer (score 5):

The basic, general meaning of *noch* is "continuity": something is "as before", although it also might change soon (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporaladverbial#Phasenadverbiale).

The various different uses, which *noch* does have, can usually be related to this underlying meaning in some way, although they tend to become idiomatic, fixed expressions as well. When you say: I will do it "noch heute" (which I take to be a somewhat fixed expression), this later time when you finally do it is presented as still connected to the time before it. So it's presented as a continuation of our present moment. That means, the speaker signals it will be done before anything else comes in between (like a new day), without delay.

If you just say "I mache es heute", it is presented more as an isolated fact, unconnected to the time of speaking, a simple choice between today and some other time.

PS:
German "noch" is a very flexible and subtle thing, and its contribution therefore often looks mysterious. It has been discussed a lot in the linguistics literature because of that (references in the above wikipedia article). One other use, mysterious at first, is "Ich dusche schnell noch, dann komm ich auch fernsehen" - "I'll *noch* take a shower, then I'll join you for TV". But this usage, too, can be understood on the same basis: my current chain of activities is continued by one more (similar) thing, i.e. taking a shower; then I'll start something new.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ich ruf dich heute an.
2. Ich ruf dich heute noch an.

The difference in the meaning of these two sentences is very subtile. The English translation of both is "I'll call you today." But sentence 1 just means that, nothing more.

Sentence 2 has an additional meaning. I try to reproduce this meaning in English:

> I would have called you in the next few days, but to do you a favor, I don't want to wait any longer than necessary, so I'll call you today.

But if you really say all that, that's very explicit information about your habits of calling other people and your relationship with the person you're going to call, so you don't really want to say all that. You're just adding a little word, and with that word you're just adding the flavor of that meaning.

Comment: Hm... That is one possible meaning, but not the only one. The 'noch' certainly puts some emphasis on 'heute', but it does not necessarily carry all that 'to do you a favor'-flavor. It can also just be neutral information, as in "I'll call you later today"(probably not in the next few minutes).

Comment: @Hulk: The main meaning of "noch heute" is "not tomorrow or even later". The main meaning is not "not in the next few minutes".

Comment: "before the end of the day" should come close

Comment: It can also mean: I know I should have called you yesterday and to make up for my forgetfulness, I will definitely call you today.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't like the other answers and decided to create a more digestible answer.

When you say "Ich rufe dich heute noch an", it's basically a passively more pressing way of saying that you WILL call you by the end of the day" although it's so subtle that you may as well ignore it. It's just a way of talking / adding a word into the middle that your brain naturally thought would fit, it doesn't change anything what so ever.

if you remove the "noch" it still means the same, there's practically no difference, don't read too much into it.

Maybe one can see the "noch" as a little way of subtle saying "I have some other stuff on my plate right now but i WILL STILL call you by the end of the day for sure".
Again, you could use "noch" even if you were scott-free for the entire day, the other person interprets it as if you said "Ich rufe dich heute an"

Answer (score 0):

every word has a meaning which changes according to context, but the most complicated language of the world, likes having sentences as long as it takes by filling it with particles and particle-likes to make it seem to be rich or sound stronger,emotional and so on. in this context "noch" is used to indicate that speaker will call not later than today. I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Note that the original sentence is ambiguous, depending on whether *noch* modifies *heute* or *anrufen*. The meaning is simple: *noch* contradicts a supposed expectation that the contrary happens.

> Ich rufe dich (heute) noch AN.
> (counter to the expectation that the speaker won't call (today))

> Ich rufe dich {noch HEUte, HEUte noch} an.
> (counter to the expectation that the call will happen tomorrow)

There are also ways to express the opposite expectation. Some new examples:

> Hast du noch Pause? Ist die Pause noch nicht vorbei?
> (counter to the expectation that the break is finished)

> Hast du keine Pause mehr? Is die Pause schon vorbei?
> (counter to the expectation that there is still break time left)